# trouble with mousewheel + scrollbars in tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar, mousewheel

i am trying to display images using tkinter and i have trouble when adding a scrollbar. I would like to be able to scroll with the mousewheel both horizontally and vertically, should the image exceed the windowsize. The problem is that the mousewheel does not work when i use a canvas.

in this code i can use mousewheel to scroll Y and shift+mousewheel to scroll X (which is exactly what i want):

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

scrollbarX = tk.Scrollbar(master)
scrollbarX.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
scrollbarY = tk.Scrollbar(master)
scrollbarY.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

listbox = tk.Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbarY.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbarX.set)

for i in range(1000):
    listbox.insert(tk.END, str(i)+"-----------------------------------------------------------------------")

listbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

scrollbarX.config(command=listbox.xview, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
scrollbarY.config(command=listbox.yview)

master.mainloop()
```

However, if i exchange the listbox with a canvas, the mouswheel does not do anything anymore. Scrolling manually still works:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

master = tk.Tk()

scrollbarX = tk.Scrollbar(master)
scrollbarX.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
scrollbarY = tk.Scrollbar(master)
scrollbarY.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

canvas = tk.Canvas(master, bd=0, xscrollcommand=scrollbarX.set, yscrollcommand=scrollbarY.set)

imagefile = "image.png"
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imagefile))
canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img, anchor="nw")

canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

scrollbarX.config(command=canvas.xview, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
scrollbarY.config(command=canvas.yview)

canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(tk.ALL))

master.mainloop()
```

I am still new to programming, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to handle the mouse events and do the scrolling.

You can do that by having a callback like this:

```
def on_mousewheel(event):
    shift = (event.state & 0x1) != 0
    scroll = -1 if event.delta > 0 else 1
    if shift:
        canvas.xview_scroll(scroll, "units")
    else:
        canvas.yview_scroll(scroll, "units")
```

Then you bind it to `canvas` like this:

```
canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", on_mousewheel)
```

Comment: Thanks. So I understand there is no built-in way when using canvas? Because it does work out of the box using a listbox.

Comment: As far as I recall, when it comes to the canvas you have to propagate mouse events and the like yourself.

Comment: That's a bummer. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: i realized a new problem when introducing the callback. if the window is bigger than the image (so there is some space at the windowborders), the scrollbars are disabled (as they should be), but i can still scroll, and now the hole image moves up and down / left and right

Comment: It's because you haven't given the canvas a fixed size. To fix that add something like this `canvas.configure(width=img.width(), height=img.height())`. Now you don't be able to scroll when the window is bigger than the image.

Comment: FYI In Linux you should bind <Button-4> and <Button-5 instead of <MouseWheel>